# Remotely terminate a Sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, web-services, workflow

Has anyone had experience canceling a workflow via webservices? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the web service yourself, it can do anything you want.

Here is a code example for cancelling workflow: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/e5fc79f8-ca3a-421a-ab8a-78fcb3365b46

**Edit**

There is a workflow.asmx, but it looks like it has a startworkflow but not a stop

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916(office.12).aspx

Comment: Very true, but I was thinking more along the lines of "out-of-the-box functionality

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using out of the box webservices. Shiraz seems to have the best option.

Comment: Ok I guess a custom ws will be the way to go